# What makes a man succeed?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> What makes a man succeed, a host a captive, and a mess into something meaningful?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I guess that would be

> **age.**

As in

> man*age* ~ succeed, host*age* ~ captive, mess*age* ~ something meaningful

Comment: This answer could also tie up Mr. Bond, and make his garb all stinky, but of course 007 would eventually be able prevent the answer from causing any harm to the dam.

Comment: It can also make bad movie sequels out of ice and track down your family with nothing but a line.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is:

> Famine
>  Or tooth loss
>  Or sexual orientation.

Because

> Succeed as the pun "suck seed" and a few takes on what could be the cause.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the [Tour]!) Unfortunately, your answer lacks an explanation of why you think it is correct, so may be deleted. Answers should be a thoughtfully considered attempt to solve the puzzle that was posed, with an explanation of how you arrived at the solution and/or why you believe your solution is correct. We're looking for quality answers, not a one-line response containing the first thing that leapt to mind. Please take some time to look around and familiarize yourself with the kinds of answers that are well-received here, ideally before you post any more answers.

Comment: @glorfindel, how's that?

Comment: Better (I still think it's not the correct answer, though.) I've added 'spoilers' for you (with `>!`) as most other answers on this site do.